# How to read Combo boxes Value from Excel using C# or asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

How to read Combo boxes Value from Excel using C#?
Trying to read Excel combo box value in c# site. but not able to get it.
This the excel which contain dropdown so whatever selected value in dropdown that should fetch:

[image: this the excel which contain dropdown so whatever selected value in dropdown that should fetch]

This one snap code which I have written but while running this code I am getting compilation error.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown allDropDowns = worksheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing);
```

At this line look like this Type. Missing not the proper one.

Even here also getting one compiler error at `.Item("1")`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown oneDropdown = allDropDowns.Item("1");
```

[This is the main error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jZvv.png)

Can't able to proceed with this.

This is full snap code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;

//Get a new workbook.
oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\\testexcel.xls"));
//3rd Sheet
oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets.get_Item(1);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns allDropDowns = oSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown oneDropdown = allDropDowns.Item("1");  
string selectedText = oneDropdown.get_List(oneDropdown.ListIndex);
```

Please any one can fix this issue.

As I have mention above issue trying to read selected dropdown value from excel.

Comment: If this Excel is available in CSV form, or can be made available in CSV form, and all you need is the data from the Excel, that's a much better path forward.

Comment: it is not form of CSV, as you can see i have dropdown in excel. that I want to read it in c# side

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete text of your compilation error(s) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. Thanks!